# Powerapps - Wrong time displayed after saving into Sharepoint List

Tags: powerapps

I'm following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-dateadd-datediff) on dates below, it gives this formula to convert to UTC,

[image]

I'm using this to update data in a sharepoint list,

This is the code that is bound to the OnSuccess(submit) of the FormControl.

[image]

Result,

it's now 5:30pm. But sharepoint gives me 6:30 pm the previous day. Am I missing something?

Debugging notes,

- Now() - gives me correct localtime in powerapps
- TimeZoneOffset() = -480
- Running on mobile, gives the same result.
- Not converting to UTC before updating sharepoint gives 11:54pm today. When it's actually 2:54pm.

Comment: You're assuming that `Now()` is in UTC - I suspect it's already in local time.

Comment: (If Now() returns 3:36pm and then you're adding the offset of 8 hours again, that would definitely explain why you're setting 11:36pm.)

Comment: @JonSkeet OMG, you're right. NOW() gives the localtime now already. The funny thing is when I save this value in Sharepoint, 5:24pm becomes 2:22am. same date.

Comment: I doubt that it changes from 5:24 to 2:22, but 5:22 to 2:22 is more plausible. It sounds like you need to look at how you're saving to Sharepoint, which we don't know anything about in terms of your code at the moment. (Never having used Sharepoint or PowerApps, nor knowing how you're checking the data in Sharepoint, I doubt that I'd personally be able to help you with that, but it suggests how you could improve your question.)

Comment: edited the question per your recommendation.

Comment: Well not really... you haven't shown how you're saving the data to Sharepoint. Maybe I just don't know PowerApps well enough, but I'd expect there to be *some* code involved.

Comment: oops I missed code snippet earlier. added. really weird to just post documentation yes.

Comment: What happens if you simply patch Now() instead of converting it to UTC?

Comment: @Meneghino it gives me 11:54pm today.
When it's actually 2:54pm.

Comment: edited the question further for clarity

Comment: I'm having this problem today using Dynamics 365 connector on a Common Data Store environment.  Were you ever able to resolve your issue, @tinker?